# Flutter - Failed to launch browser. Make sure you are using an up-to-date Chrome or Edge

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome, web, flutter-web

I am having a problem when I try to run my flutter application on chrome I get this error

Failed to launch browser. Make sure you are using an up-to-date Chrome or Edge. Otherwise, consider using -d web-server instead and filing an issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

I have tried to run flutter doctor and this is the outcome :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.5.0-5.2.pre, on Ubuntu 21.04 5.11.0-31-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• No issues found!
```

I have tried everything but nothing seems to work

thanks in advance for your responses

Comment: Tried running the app with cmd?

Comment: I am on Linux, but I have tried this Command : run -d chrome, and it's not  working

Comment: Can you try ’flutter run -d chrome’

Comment: I have tried  that too still the same problem

Comment: @saeedbayat did you find out the problem?

Comment: @andriyantonov I deleted the flutter sdk and installed it again and it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalling flutter sdk worked for me